# Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path Error occurred with Same URI GET and POST

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to make controller using same URI with GET and POST request. But I came across the following error.

```
Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8080/boards/forgotPassword/recoverForm':
```

As far as I know, It shouldn't happen since one use GET request and The other use POST. If I'm wrong, please correct me. The Controller details below.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgotPassword", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class PasswordResetController {

    @ModelAttribute("userEmail")
    public UserEmail makeUserEmailDTO () {
        UserEmail userEmail = new UserEmail();
        return userEmail;
    }

    //@RequestMapping(value = "/recoverForm", method = RequestMethod.GET) --> same error
    @GetMapping("/recoverForm")
    public String getRecoverForm () {

        return "_recoverForm";
    }

    //@RequestMapping(value = "/recoverForm", method = RequestMethod.POST) --> same error
    @PostMapping("/recoverForm")
    public String sendRecoverEmail (@ModelAttribute("userEmail") @Valid UserEmail userEmail, BindingResult result) {

        System.out.println(userEmail.getEmail());
        return "_temp";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the 'method = RequestMethod.GET' from 3th line. This attribute defines GET to all methods above.